# How filter csv by row name in R

Tags: r, csv

I have a csv file with over 100 names with different background/ demographic information (see sample example below):

| Name | Data | 2000 | 2001 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pam | Job | Analyst | Associate |
| Jim | Job | Manager | Director |
| Steve | Job | Manager | Director |
| Dave | Job | Manager | Manager |
| Pam | Salary | 50000 | 65000 |
| Jim | Salary | 100000 | 120000 |
| Steve | Salary | 100000 | 120000 |
| Dave | Salary | 90000 | 90000 |

How can I filter the csv file by name (let’s say I only want to see Pam and Dave) and by data (Job only). Of course I want to do this on a large scale (ideally I’d like to filter the original file which has 100 names down to twenty specific names and the 20 data down to 10).

Answer (score 0):

```
> df
       Name   Data   X2000     X2001
    1   Pam    Job Analyst Associate
    2   Jim    Job Manager  Director
    3 Steve    Job Manager  Director
    4  Dave    Job Manager   Manager
    5   Pam Salary   50000     65000
    6   Jim Salary  100000    120000
    7 Steve Salary  100000    120000
    8  Dave Salary   90000     90000
```

In order to filter on the name Pam and Dave, and by data job i use the `filter` function:

```
df <- 
  df %>%
  filter((Name == "Pam" | Name == "Dave"))
```

After filtering their names you can filter the Data column as well:

```
df <- 
  df %>%
  filter((Data == "Job"))
```

I get:

```
  Name Data   X2000     X2001
1  Pam  Job Analyst Associate
2 Dave  Job Manager   Manager
```

Comment: Thank you but is there a way to do this on a large scale. Let’s say you want to filter the csv down to 50 names?

Answer (score 0):

We can first create two vectors with the 20 names and 10 data that you want to filter. Here is an example with three names and two data.

```
vnames<-c("Pam", "Jim", "Steve")
vdata<-c("Job", "Salary")
```

We can then create a filtered dataframe (filtered) applying a subset to your initial dataframe (df)

```
filtered<-subset(df, Name %in% vnames & Data %in% vdata)
```